# Auto update date time 1 times per day?

Tags: timestamp

How to update automatically date time of page to current time only 1 time per day?

Example: I write a post on May 28, 2013. And if today is June 9, it will change may 28 to June 9. And if today is June 10, it will change June 9 to June 10.

How to do this? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [wp_cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );
```

And then you define `my_task_function()` updating the post date.

Comment: I am not coder. So can you give me a full code, please ? Thank you very much !

Comment: pastebin.com/6sqXgvgR . Is it right ? Thank you !